# Is there anyway to see things I flagged in Area51?

Tags: support, area-51, flag-history

In any SE site, from my account page, I can see things I flagged. But in Area51, I can't see such option in my account page. How can I see the history of my flags or what action were taken etc.?

Comment: There isn't any way to do so.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy , Well that's a bit disappointing, isn't it? Why is this exception in case of Area51?

Comment: area51 doesn't follow many features from other SE sites. Its builds are separate.

Comment: It's an SE 1.0 site, actually

Answer (score 1):

**Area51 is a StackExchange 1.0 site and on it there is not any possibility to do that.** You can make a feature request, but I think it will be not approved.